# Assign column value of dataframe where columns of two dataframes are equal

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, functional-programming, apply

I have 2 dataframes. I want to assign the `value of df1.column1 = df2.column1 where df1.column2 == df2.column2 and df1.column3 == df2.column3 and df1.column4 == df2.column4.`

I am using the below function but it is taking a very long time when the two dataframes are large. Any suggestions to speed up the code using python?

```
def f(x):
  for row in df2.iloc:
    if x['name'] == row['name'] and x['age'] == row['age'] and x['gender'] == row['gender']:
      return row['occupation']

df1['occupation'] = df1.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to find where they are all equal and use .loc indexing to replace the values in appropriate locations

```
idx = (df1.name == df2.name) & (df1.age == df2.age) & (df1.gender == df2.gender)
df1.loc[idx, 'occupation'] = df2.loc[idx, 'occupation']
```

Here is a demonstration of how this works.

df1

```
   A  B  C  D
0  a  b  1  x
1  b  a  2  r
2  a  c  3  q
```

df2

```
     A  B  C    D
0    a  b  1  fff
1  NaN  a  2  ggg
2    a  c  3  hhh
```

Find where A and B are equal and replace column D in df1 with column D in df2:

```
idx = (df1.A == df2.A) & (df1.B == df2.B)
df1.loc[idx, 'D'] = df2.loc[idx, 'D']
```

df1

```
   A  B  C    D
0  a  b  1  fff
1  b  a  2    r
2  a  c  3  hhh
```

For your next post please consult [this guide on how to produce a minimum reproducible code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

------EDIT-----

If `df2` has less rows than `df1` then the above method will not work. In this case you could do:

df2

```
     A  B  C    D
0    a  b  1  fff
1  NaN  a  2  ggg
```

Then

```
dfm = df1[df1.index.isin(df2.index)]
idx = (dfm.A == df2.A) & (dfm.B == df2.B)
dfm.loc[idx, 'D'] = df2.loc[idx, 'D']
df1 = dfm.combine_first(df1)
```

df1

```
   A  B    C    D
0  a  b  1.0  fff
1  b  a  2.0    r
2  a  c  3.0    q
```

Comment: Great job eNc. I got a error saying: "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects" when I tried the code on the dataframes.

Comment: @BoPeng so your dataframes must either have different indices or different number of rows. This is why its important to provide an example of each dataframe and the expected result. I have added a soln for the case where the indicies are numbered the same, but there are less rows in df2.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I actually used the solution below but I appreciate your help and efforts and will give you the checkmark because of it.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the method below.

```
  def f(x):
          row = df1.loc[(df1['name'] == x['name']) & (df1['age'] == x['age']) & (df1['gender'] == x['gender'])]
          return row['occupation'].item()

  df2['occupation'] = df2.apply(f, axis=1)
```